# Button on each item in drop down list

Tags: javascript, angular, button, dropdown, angular2-template

I have a dropdown list and I want to have a button for each item in list.
But when I click on button the focus on the button (`btn-add-list`) is gone, so the list is gone too.

My code:

```
<button class="btn-add-list><i class="material-icons">note_add</i></button>
 <ul id="dropdown-add-list">
    <li class="list-item">List 1
       <button (click)="addItemToList('list')">+</button>
     </li>

     <li >List 2
        <button (click)="addItemToList('list')">+</button>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

css:

```
.btn-add-list:focus ~ #dropdown-add-list{
  display: bloc;
}

#dropdown-add-list{
display:none;
position: relative:;
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `stopPropagation()` to your click event in order to stop click event to propagate to `li` (basically, when you click, only button will be clicked, not `li`):

```
<li class="list-item">List 1
   <button (click)="addItemToList('list');$event.stopPropagation()">+</button>
 </li>

<li >List 2
    <button (click)="addItemToList('list');$event.stopPropagation()">+</button>
</li>
```

Read more about `stopPropagation()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Also, you closed your `<button>` tags with `</span>` tag instead of `</button>`.

Comment: I want to click the button as many times as I want without closing the dropdown. I put the **$event.stopPropagation()** but it's not working. But thank you, i found that i need to use (mousedown)=false", to stop the propagation and don't lose the focus on the parent button